# Is it possible to pass a class type and use as return type?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method which uses a parser, the parser call example is:

```
SpecificClass ret = parser.parse(getOutputStream(),SpecificClass.class);
```

note that the return type is THE SAME as the one specified as paramether.

Now, I'd like to create a method which does this call and returns the specific class type I want.
For example:

```
public $$some construct I don't know$$ invokeParser(Class<?> c){
      //... operations....
      return parser.parse(getOutputStream(),c); //c works, I can pass it
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Make your method generic. Use the type variable as the return type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make the method generic.  Declare your type parameter with `<T>` and return a `T`.

```
public <T> T invokeParser(Class<T> c) {
```

Comment: Very nice! And tell me: would it be possible to make this type as a generic BUT subclassing a specific class? I define a mother class and then a type T which could be anything subclassing that class. This is so I can call some methods on the T object while still in the function without having to cast.

Comment: @Phate Yes, use `<T extends MotherClass>`, although `T` could also be `MotherClass` itself.